# TypeScript type definition to export named React component from JavaScript library path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Grommet is a React UI library with no TypeScript types. I am trying to make a basic definition file allowing each component to be imported as a named import React component type. Reason: convenience so an editor can find them by name to auto import, e.g.

```
import { Button, AddIcon } from 'grommet'
```

I've tried various options. So far the closest I have is the following, which is wrong, but perhaps can be corrected:

```
/// <reference types="react" />
import * as React from 'react';

declare module 'grommet' {
  // I don't think this actually does anything, but I would like to grab just this
  import * as Button from 'grommet/components/Button';

  // this works, but when I use the debugger, I think it comes from the root index.js file
  export class Button extends React.Component<any, any> {}

  // somehow export AddIcon would be nice
}

declare module 'grommet/components/icons/base' {
  // I want to grab this Add component which is default
  import * as AddIcon from 'grommet/components/icons/base/Add';

  // somehow turn it into a React component type and export it as name AddIcon
  export class AddIcon extends React.Component<any, any> {}
}
```

What I think happens now is the 'grommet' module picks up the root [index.js](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/blob/6983f712c48aa014bf5ae0e1ad26ecef926d7474/src/js/index.js) file and imports all the components. Button is working correctly, but I am not sure if it is possible to just import Button and not everything as a form of tree shaking via TypeScript definitions.

Two issues I would like to solve:

1. How to import Add as a named import React component typed `{ AddIcon }` from `'grommet'`, or just `'grommet/components/icons/base'` if that is not possible.
2. Be able to import the individual components from their path instead of bringing in all of grommet. Preferably via `'grommet'` as a nice to have optimization, or e.g. `'grommet/components/Button'`.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to make typescript to do tree shaking, apart from importing each and every module like `grommet/components/Button` in your `.ts` source files. The way you structure inner modules in your type definitions has no effect on item 2 in your question. From typescript point of view,  `import {something} from 'grommet'` always assumes loading `grommet` module as a whole, removing unused parts is not an optimization typescript is concerned with, it belongs to module loader or bundler level.

Comment: Yes, I think you are probably right. Previously I had either used `const Button = require('grommet/components/Button');` or made an `index.ts` file where I imported the JavaScript files I wanted and then re-exported them as named imports